# Android / Использовать plural-правила русского, когда на телефоне установлен другой язык

Tags: android, локализация, locale

В приложении используется только русская локализация. Все строки лежат в `values/strings.xml`
В том числе вот такой plural:

```
<plurals name="days_left">
    <item quantity="one">Остался %d день</item>
    <item quantity="few">Осталось %d дня</item>
    <item quantity="many">Осталось %d дней</item>
</plurals>
```

Если на телефоне установить, например, английский язык, то правила множественного числа для русского языка не применяются и используются те, что присущи установленному языку. Конкретно в данном случае, не работает `few`, и для 2, 3, 4 подставляется выражение из `many`: *Осталось 2 дней*

Возможно ли принудительно использовать требуемую локаль, для правил множественного числа? Как, например, это сделано в `String.format(Locale l, String format, Object... args)`

Answer (score 7):

Начиная с Api 17 вы можете получить ресурсы для конкретной локали:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
public Resources getResourcesByLocale() {
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration(getResources().getConfiguration());
    configuration.setLocale(new Locale("ru"));

    return createConfigurationContext(configuration).getResources();
}
```

И соответственно потом из этих локализованных ресурсов вытаскивать plurals:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    String daysLeft = getResourcesByLocale().getQuantityString(R.plurals.days_left, i, i);
    Log.i("Plurals", daysLeft);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Попробуйте установить локаль принудительно на русскую на уровне приложения как-то [так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23560270/3212712):

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

        newConfig.locale = new Locale("ru");
        Locale.setDefault(new Locale("ru"));
        getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(newConfig, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Locale.setDefault(new Locale("ru"));
        config.locale = new Locale("ru");
        getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }
}
```